# File not found Error in Python while the file already exists

Tags: python-3.x, csv, path

I want to add some data set in python.but it show file not found error,but the file path is correct.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnsjU.png)

I changed the location of the file and changed the name nothing worked. i location syntax

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\city_day.csv')
```

and

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\city_day.csv')
```

etc..

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use r'path' instead of '"path"'.
Other option is to use the path with double slashes, like: "C:\\dir\\file.csv"

In your case, it should be something like:

```py
pd.read_csv(r'C:\city_day.csv')
```

or

```py
pd.read_csv(r'C:\\city_day.csv')
```

Comment: [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is better option than using raw strings.

Comment: making assumptions on the operating system. windows would be "/" or "\\", whereas `os.path.join()` would be agnostic to the operating system...